# Identification of duplicate multiples emails for user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have User and UserEmails models.

User columns: id, first_name, last_name
UserEmails: id, user_id, email, primary

I need a function like this(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVzrq.jpg)

The essence is this: duplicate users are identified by or emails.

Example:
User 1:

```
{ id: 1, first_name: 'Test', last_name: 'User1' }
```

UserEmails for User 1:

```
{ email: 'same_email3@test.com', primary: true, user_id: 1 }
```

User 2:

```
{ id: 2, first_name: 'Test', last_name: 'User2' }
```

UserEmails for User 2:

```
{ { email: 'same_email@test.com', primary: true, user_id: 2 }, { email: 'same_email1@test.com', primary: false, user_id: 2 }, { email: 'same_email3@test.com', primary: false, user_id: 2 } }
```

User 3:

```
{ id: 3, first_name: 'Test', last_name: 'User3' }
```

UserEmails for User 3:

```
{ { email: 'same_email@test.com', primary: true, user_id: 3 }, { email: 'same_email3@test.com', primary: false, user_id: 3 }, { email: 'same_email4@test.com', primary: false, user_id: 3 } }
```

I need a query which will find that duplicates and return an ids array like this:
`[[1, 2, 3], [...]]`

I have a query but it incorrectly displays an array of ids:

```
ids = User.left_outer_joins(:user_emails)
          .select('array_agg(users.id) AS ids')
          .where('user_emails.email IS NOT NULL')             
          .group("user_emails.email")
          .having('COUNT(1) > 1')
          .map(&:ids)
```

I get this array, but the array `[2, 3]` is already in the array `[1,2,3]`.

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3]]
```

How I can group or sort the array ids that would not be duplicated in case of display of users which are duplicates by email?

Answer (score 0):

You can try self join to find duplication

```
select distinct(u1.user_id) from public.UserEmails u1, public.UserEmails u2
where u1.email = u2.email
```